# MockMvc for SpringBoot with controller advice exception handler and webAppContextSetup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I have an environment which requires MockMvc to be created with full WebApplicationContext.
Using this annotation `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` or this line in a setUp() method:
`MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()`.

I cannot use standalone controller version of the MockMvc `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()` for it requires fairly complex configuration to work.

I've learned from various articles that for some strange reason the MockMvc is created without proper controller advice setups. As a result, the responses are totally different for scenarios when error handling is expected but not wired in test environment.

I wonder if there's any way to make the MockMvc setup similar to the Spring Boot application, which includes exception handlers.

If not possible, I wonder if there's any way to test error scenarios intelligently considering the limitation.

I understand that standalone setup allows to manually add controller advice via `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.setControllerAdvice()` making it simple.
Unfortunately, I have to stick to the webAppContextSetup and the `DefaultMockMvcBuilder` has no such method.

UPDATE:

The tests are annotated with the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional
@WithMockUser(username = "test", roles = { "role1" })
```

The exception handler is annotated with

```
@RestControllerAdvice
```

UPDATE2:

The following annotation was added to the MyApplication class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xyz", "com.xyz.config"})
```

where com.xyz is the main package, where MyApplication class lies and com.xyz.config is the package of the exception handler.
It didn't help.

Comment: Can you share package for `MyApplication.class` and `RestControllerAdvice` annotated class ?

Comment: RestControllerAdvice is a standard spring annotation here: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation. Package for MyApplication class can be anything. For instance, test.MyApplication.

Comment: What I meant, if `RestControllerAdvice` annotated class is not part of main package which has your `MyApplication`, it won't be scanned and hence won't work. if it is outside of `MyApplication`, please add it in `base-packages`. I hope that helps.  For Example. if Myapplication is inside of "org.xyz", 'controllerAdvice' should be inside that package or specified in base packages for component scan.

Comment: I see. The exception handler is in a sub-package and is expected to get picked up automatically. Nevertheless, I did as you suggested (see UPDATE2 in the question). The result is the same.